# Convert 16bits register with dart to float

Tags: flutter, dart, modbus

i have to do this conversions:

// 2 Modbus register to float 32

[21946, 17562] need to become a float 32bit -> 1234,6789

// 4 Modbus register to double

[50437, 12687, 19127, 16531] need to become a double -> 1234,67890000

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some inspiration. Dart does not have a `float` type so `getFloat32` will return a `double`.

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() {
  final float32Data = ByteData(4)
    ..setUint16(0, 17562)
    ..setUint16(2, 21946);
  print(float32Data.getFloat32(0)); // 1234.678955078125

  final doubleData = ByteData(8)
    ..setUint16(0, 16531)
    ..setUint16(2, 19127)
    ..setUint16(4, 12687)
    ..setUint16(6, 50437);
  print(doubleData.getFloat64(0)); // 1234.6789
}
```